# Throttle CPU to reduce fan usage on MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, performance, cpu, temperature

I am using an MBP (late '19, 8-Core i9, macOS 12.5). On medium and heavy usage, the fans kick in, as expected. However, I sometimes want to use the MBP casually and would be willing to throttle down the CPU to decrease/eliminate the likelihood of the fans kicking in. Is there a relatively safe way to do that? I noticed that starting Siri pauses the fans, probably combined with throttling the CPU.
Does anybody know a good way to approach this?

Comment: I've always just used Macs Fan Control to control the fan speed down to a noise level I'm okay with. The CPU auto throttles to the new thermal envelope.

Comment: @At0mic Thanks for the suggestion! Do you feel like that is a safe option, e.g. the MBP operates like an MBA and reduces performance if necessary, or do I need to consider heating issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from fiddling with tools that can change the fan speed (which can potentially be risky), you can also put to sleep some (but not all!  ) of the CPU cores.

First, find out how many CPU cores you have:

```bash
sysctl -n hw.ncpu
```

For example, if the command above shows you have `16` CPU cores you can put half of them to sleep by running the following from the terminal:

```bash
sudo cpuctl offline 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Put the cores back online:

```bash
sudo cpuctl online 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

View the online/offline state of the CPU cores:

```bash
sudo cpuctl list
```

> ❗️❗️ Do NOT pull *all* the cores offline, or otherwise your mac will crash!

If you feel nostalgic and want to re-experience the performance of pre-mswindows intel 386 computers then leave a single core online. Having only one core active will reduce *both* the fan noise *and* performance.

For details also see in terminal the manpages for:

```bash
man sysctl

man cpuctl
```

> NOTE: This only works on Intel macs, but does not (yet?) work on Apple Silicon M1/M2/M3 chips.

---

> To visualize real-time CPU cores usage double-click the CPU LOAD graph in the `Activity Monitor.app`.

This is what you might see with only a single core online:

[image]

Comment: `sudo cpuctl list` says that one of the CPUs is the master. It seems like it might be best to avoid taking that one offline, but I don't know maybe it would be harmless.

Comment: no big deal, it will just freeze the system and you'll need to do a rough reboot; btw, this still doesn't seem to affect apple silicon cores, not clear if apple is going to ever fix it, or remove the command altogether on m1..m3